# I get correct redirection after clicking on ASP.NET button but not in a new window as specified

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, new-window

Clicking on ASP.NET button redirects to correct website but on the same tab, not in a new tab what i need to do. What's wrong with the code  `OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"` below? Why it is not enough alone and what else need to be done?

The following ASP.NET code for the button control is:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGenerateReport" runat="server" Text="Generate Report" 
OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking out for server side code to open a new window on Button Click, then here's how to do so.

Add the following script to the  section of your page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openNewWin(url) {
        var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1');
        x.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Then add a Button Control in the following manner

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpenPop" runat="server" Text="Open Pop"           
    onclick="btnOpenPop_Click" />
```

Finally add some code in the code behind file

```
protected void btnOpenPop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://www.dotnetcurry.com";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openNewWin('" + url + "')</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know two methods for redirecting the page to new tab in **asp**

> 1) The first method which you are already using and it works also. Make an onclientclick event of Button and on code behind of Button
>   Click write the following code:-

```
button.OnClientClick = "aspnetForm.target='_blank'"; Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx");
```

> 2)You can also use javascript

```
 button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('yourpage.aspx');return false;");
```

Both the method will redirect your page to new tab on clicking the button.

The error with your code is **OnClientClick = "aspnetForm.target='_blank;'"** remove the semicolon after '_blank' and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can't use target attribute on button.

You have to use javascript function `window.open()`

Check this:

[Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Thank you. So for some things C# can't do much on its own without javascript then...

Answer (score 0):

I don't post links lightly, but I found this site explains all and it has solved my problem too.

http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/open-new-window-in-aspnet-web-page_28.html